# Mixed C/Java OSGi Platform

Tags: java, c, osgi, apache-felix, apache-celix

is there a way of having a language-mixed component framework like OSGi? I'd like to mix modules or bundles that are written in C and Java. On the site of NativeOSGi (https://github.com/abroekhuis/NativeOSGi) there is a hint, however the project seems to be not maintained anymore. Is there a way of getting Apache Celix and Felix to work together?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of making Felix and Celix work together is through the OSGi Remote Services specification. Work is currently being done to make Amdatu Remote (an implementation of that specification) interoperate with Celix. I would encourage you to ask on the Celix mailing list, as they can probably tell you more about its current status.

Comment: please check my comment to the question of Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Like Marcel said, the best way to go would be using Remote Services.
Since the Amdatu Remote Services has been working on a new release I am not sure if the current version is compatible with the Celix implementation. If this is not the case, we should work on getting it up and running again.

You mentioned NativeOSGi, and while the github page isn't maintained, we are still working on it (sadly a bit slow..). Basically the idea is to make Celix implement the NativeOSGi API (or base the NativeOSGi API on Celix, just a matter of perspective). Since Celix has had a 1.0 release, we have started working on the API, so expect to see some progress on the trunk wrt NativeOSGi.

I hope this helps a bit, if there are any other questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: well yea, but how do remote services affect the performance? I'd like to run the C part inside of a real-time thread, s.t. binding services via function calls would be really appreciate the most performant solution.

Comment: You use "remote" services only when going from Java to C or vise versa. If real-time components communicate within Celix, you're basically just invoking functions.

Comment: @MarcelOffermans can I have multiple threads in Celix, probably yes.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just like in Java there is nothing in the framework that restricts that.

Comment: If you have any more detailed questions regarding Celix, feel free to contact the Celix mailing list. The list is watched by the committers of the project. But as Marcel said, there are no restrictions in the framework that would prevent anything wrt threads.